# Turbo C++ 3D rotation issue

Tags: c++, turbo-c++, bgi

First off, please don't ask why I'm using an outdated software. I'm just messing with Turbo C++ as a fun way to start off with simple programs. I'm trying to create an old school 3D engine that runs on the CPU. I first tried making it rotate a simple 3D box on the Z axis. Since it's rotating through the Z axis, it should look like a 2D box rotating. But when I run the code, it doesn't even project the vertices in the right position.

Please excuse me for the way I type my code.

```
    void Render3D(float VDATA[],float CFRAME[]) { 
    if (VDATA!=NULL) { float POINT[2]; float OLDPOINT[2]; float AXIS=0; 
    for (int P=0; P<24; P=P+1) { AXIS=AXIS+1; if (AXIS==1) { POINT[0]=VDATA[P]; }
    if (AXIS==2) { POINT[1]=VDATA[P]; } if (AXIS==3) { POINT[2]=VDATA[P]; if (CFRAME!=NULL) { 
    OLDPOINT[0]=POINT[0]; OLDPOINT[1]=POINT[1]; OLDPOINT[2]=POINT[2];
    POINT[0]=OLDPOINT[0]*cos(CFRAME[8])-OLDPOINT[1]*sin(CFRAME[8]);
    POINT[1]=OLDPOINT[0]*sin(CFRAME[8])+OLDPOINT[1]*cos(CFRAME[8]);
    OLDPOINT[0]=POINT[0]; OLDPOINT[1]=POINT[1]; OLDPOINT[2]=POINT[2];
    POINT[1]=OLDPOINT[1]*cos(CFRAME[7])-OLDPOINT[2]*sin(CFRAME[7]);
    POINT[2]=OLDPOINT[1]*sin(CFRAME[7])+OLDPOINT[2]*cos(CFRAME[7]);
    OLDPOINT[0]=POINT[0]; OLDPOINT[1]=POINT[1]; OLDPOINT[2]=POINT[2];
    POINT[2]=OLDPOINT[2]*cos(CFRAME[6])-OLDPOINT[0]*sin(CFRAME[6]);
    POINT[0]=OLDPOINT[2]*sin(CFRAME[6])+OLDPOINT[0]*cos(CFRAME[6]);
    POINT[0]=POINT[0]+CFRAME[3]; POINT[1]=POINT[1]+CFRAME[4]; POINT[2]=POINT[2]+CFRAME[5]; } 
    cout<<POINT[0]<<","<<POINT[1]<<","<<POINT[2]<<endl;
    putpixel(POINT[0],POINT[1],7); AXIS=0; POINT[0]=0; POINT[1]=0; POINT[2]=0; } } } }

    void main() { int Driver=DETECT,Mode; initgraph(&Driver,&Mode,"BGI"); 
    clrscr(); cleardevice(); 

    float VDATA[23]; float CFRAME[8]; CFRAME[3]=200; CFRAME[4]=200; CFRAME[5]=0;
    VDATA[0]=-50; VDATA[1]=-50; VDATA[2]=-50;
    VDATA[3]=-50; VDATA[4]=50; VDATA[5]=-50;
    VDATA[6]=50; VDATA[7]=-50; VDATA[8]=-50;
    VDATA[9]=50; VDATA[10]=50; VDATA[11]=-50;
    VDATA[12]=-50; VDATA[13]=-50; VDATA[14]=50;
    VDATA[15]=-50; VDATA[16]=50; VDATA[17]=50;
    VDATA[18]=50; VDATA[19]=-50; VDATA[20]=50;
    VDATA[21]=50; VDATA[22]=50; VDATA[23]=50; 

    while (1>0) { clrscr(); cleardevice(); Render3D(VDATA,CFRAME); 
    CFRAME[8]=CFRAME[8]+0.01; getch(); }

    clrscr(); cleardevice(); closegraph(); }
```

The VDATA[23] array holds the points for a cube. The CFRAME[8] array holds the coordinate frame information. The first three elements can be ignored. But CFRAME[3],CFRAME[4],CFRAME[5] sets the offset of the cube in XYZ. And CFRAME[6],CFRAME[7],CFRAME[8] sets the rotation of the cube in XYZ. But when I run the code, it displays something like this:

https://i.gyazo.com/a8c0d62b03e14aa10e2bc93027fb3f05.png

It should display a box but it doesn't.

Comment: Please indent your code when you post at SO. Much more likely to get somebody to look at it.... Also, you are drawing just corner pixels? Try drawing the lines, to better see what is going on.

Comment: You don't exactly need to look at the pixels when I display the XYZ of the coordinates as well. There's no need to draw lines as it wouldn't change anything and would be even more confusing seeing a single line on the screen. I also like typing my code this way because I'd rather see all of the code without having them overlap the window and needing to scroll to the side to see it.

Comment: For anyone else who encounters this thread, please don't talk about making it "look better" or asking something that won't help either one of us. This is my first post, and I'll indent my future codings next time as I don't want to have a continuous conversation of making my code look neater. Thank you. :)

Comment: Note that you can edit also this question to improve code formatting. Which you should probably do, in case nobody answers your question. As a side note, doesn't Turbo C++ give you any warnings when you compile the code? Try upping the warning level, if it's possible.

Comment: Well it's not the issue of errors here. It's just the issue of my equation I made. And I'm pretty sure that Turbo C++ will give me a warning if there is one at any point.

Answer (score 0):

The first problem you have is, you have one element too short arrays, for example

```
float POINT[2];
```

and then in many places you access `POINT[2]`... In C, when you define an array, you tell the number of elements in it, so above you create `POINT` array with two elements, which are with indexes 0 and 1. Accessing `POINT[2]` goes out of array bounds, which is *undefined behaviour*.

So what you want is, for example:

```
float POINT[3]; // valid indexes 0..2
```

And of course same fix for every array where you have the same mistake.

---

A decent compiler with warnings enabled should warn you about code like that, since the compiler knows the array size at compile time.

The code may have other problems, but it's pointless trying to fix them as long as you have *undefined behaviour*, because that essentially means, your program can do anything a program can do (including working seemingly correctly, and emptying your bank account next time you use Internet banking, and everything between and beyond).

Comment: In Turbo C++, an array starts at 0. I don't know why but that's how it works. And I made sure it got all of the points by printing them which you saw in the picture. But, thanks for the help. :) I rewrote the code in Lua this time and it works perfectly. I later on figured out the issue I had and solved it. Here's the lua version I made: https://i.gyazo.com/0c20c30404a4a284cf5265823dafe660.gif

Comment: In C array indexes start at 0, so "Some reason" is C standard.  When you define array, you don't specify last index, you specify *size*, so last valid index is one less. Anyway, switching to Lua for learning/playing around is probably good idea, much nicer, less time spent debugging low level bugs like out-of-bounds array indexes.

Comment: Btw, as you are new at SO: if you consider the issue resolved, you can accept the best (in your opinion) answer (tick mark at upper left corner). Of course if you want more answers, or if none of the answers are good enough, then leave it unaccepted.

Comment: One more note about what happens in your program here, when you access out-of-bounds array indexes: You actually access the next/previous local variable, reading or changing its value. Writing to `POINT[2]` probably also changes `OLDPOINT[0]` and vice versa, for example (simplified).